# Do we want to make "FAQ threads"?

Tags: discussion

Over the time we will have more and more questions like "What is the best choice in price range x to y" etc...

I am thinking of making this mainly for PC sets/laptops. Do we want to create a big thread with community wiki answers?

We could point this out to the new users rather than marking their questions as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

I'd be against doing this right now. Once we have precedent (meaning those questions are *actually being asked*), we should revisit this.

That said, "What is the best choice in price range x to y" is off topic here - there isn't enough information. We should be closing those questions, not answering them.

Comment: I know that simple questions like this are off-topic but I meant something more categorized: price range, requirements, usage, terms of warranty etc etc...

Comment: @belford Maybe I don't understand - do you want to create a question for every combination of price + warranty + usage?

Comment: Trying to find every combination is impossible but we could make several narrower groups: gaming/programming/design/data science etc... Gathering such questions in one place could be useful.

Comment: @belford I'm having a hard time seeing what advantage we gain by doing that instead of just closing later questions as a duplicate of the first one, if they are indeed duplicates.

Comment: Mainly I was thinking about search engines and linking our site. Top position on Google can help us to get new users - these keywords are very popular (like "best laptop for..." or "gaming laptop under $1000"). If they see this thread earlier they may not asking so many questions on the same topic.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are *very* good at SEO - getting on Google is no issue. I'd vote to let this happen organically instead of trying to force it.

Comment: Yet I'm with @belford that it would be useful if we added a bunch of questions for realistic, predictable hardware recommendation questions which we know people are searching answers for.